# no wi-fi connections visible

Tags: wireless, drivers, software-sources

laptop:  MSI CR61 Dual Core 4GB 500GB HD8210G 
wi-fi card: Realtek RTL8723AE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC
system: ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64
experience with ubuntu: beginner

problem:
wi-fi connection is not visible

---

I don't have cable connection, so solution with apt-get are not available

where can I download driver files for that card? (using windows)

---

[view1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pH5Xz.jpg)

[view2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moh11.jpg)

---

edit:
I need to somehow get drivers, download them on windows and then run them on Ubuntu (can't find url for drivers that is still active)
all links to drivers I found are inactive,
other solutions I found use cable connection and apt-get, which doesn't work for me

Comment: Hi - Please see [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) to get the information that will be needed to help with your problem.

Comment: You can download the drivers manually. Download `dkms` package from Ubuntu repositories and `rtlwifi-new-dkms` from my ppa.

Comment: If you don't have an internet connection on the target system, take a look at [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](/q/974/175814)

Answer (score -1):

Try with this on the console.

```
sudo rfkill list
```

it should show you if your wifi card is soft or hard blocked.

```
0: samsung-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no <---- THIS COULD BE YES
    Hard blocked: no <---- THIS COULD BE YES
1: samsung-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
8: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

It happens on my laptop whenever I close the screen and reopen it. For some reason the wlan does not come up automatically. I had to write a script to unblock my card.

To unblock just execute this command on the console

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: it's all set to "no"